# Finding grandparent of an element using xpath in selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, xpath, ruby, cucumber

I want to click the parent of an element if the text within the child matches a certain string. I am using `contains` to find the text and `:xpath,"../../"` to find the parent. 
Here is ruby code:

```
 test=@driver.find_element(:xpath,"//*[contains(.,'602384710')]")
puts test
 puts test.find_element(:xpath, "../..").click
```

The HTML snippet of the element I want to target is:

```
<a class="tv-card-link" href="/my-account/tv/overview?ban=7AhDHZ0ZYFVI1m8B2HmvrQ&tv_instance_id=_A5Xvou4fk-WsIWSnSkG2A">

    <div class="tv-card-wrapper">
        <div class="tv-card-icon"></div>
        <div class="tv-card-details">
            <div class="tv-card-id">
                        602384710
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

From the code, I want to click on the `<a>` if I find the text `602384710`.
When I was testing, the `puts test` prints out the address of Selenium WebElement so I know that works. However, selenium is unable to find the parent of the element. The error I get is:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"../.."} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
[remote server] file:///C:/Users/X169804/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20150407-7120-6gmcur/extensions/fxdriver@go
oglecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10271:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_'
[remote server] file:///C:/Users/X169804/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20150407-7120-6gmcur/extensions/fxdriver@go
oglecode.com/components/driver-component.js:603:in `fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify'
./features/step_definitions/ss-login_step.rb:26:in `/^I click on plan number (\d+)$/'
features\ss-login.feature:16:in `Then I click on plan number 602384710'
```

I think I may be missing a simple thing. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

If you're using findElement relative to another WebElement, your XPath needs to start with a dot (the element as your starting point). See the accepted answer [in this topic](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10014/selenium-webdriver-findelement-in-scope-of-webelement-doesnt-work).

Alternatively, the XPath `contains` goes looking in child nodes too.
You could try to immediately target the link element like so:
    `"//a[@class='tv-card-link' and contains(.,'602384710')]"`

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your answer. I used the `.` as in `test.find_element(:xpath, "./../..").click` but that gives me the same error.

Comment: I think that your first XPath is wrong, why do you use the * symbol? This will likely return the topmost html tag (because the html itself also contains that value). Do you have a link to this page for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this XPath online. Please try:

```
//a[contains(.//div,602384710)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess without any testing, but shouldn't it just be:

```
find_element(:xpath,"//*[contains(.,'602384710')]../..").click
```

The problem is that when searching with the results of a find_element it cannot go back up the tree anymore, from then on it will only search within the already found results.