# Selecting multiple options and deselecting options using Selenium with python

Tags: selenium, python

I am trying to open a webpage and select options before submitting the form. The issue I am having is being able to selecting more than one option in the select box. Eventually I want to be able to deselect an option as well and submit the the form.

A snippet of the relevant html and python code is below

Snippet of html:

```
<select size="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$lbCommodity" multiple="multiple" id="ctl00_MainContent_lbCommodity">
    <option value="101">Wheat - HRW</option>
    <option value="102">Wheat - SRW</option>
    <option value="103">Wheat - HRS</option>
    <option value="104">Wheat - White</option>
    <option value="105">Wheat - Durum</option>
```

Python code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://apps.fas.usda.gov/esrquery/esrq.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='ctl00$MainContent$lbCommodity']/option[@value='801']").click()
```

Comment: Hi Moj: can you give more detail about what goes wrong when you run your test, and what your expected result was? If there is an error, some detail from that would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. read up on Select object - http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=select#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select
2. Use IDs or names, or even CSS before XPATH. Best practices, [explained here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8470/how-can-i-structure-selenium-tests-in-a-way-that-minimises-the-maintenance-work/8491#8491)

Comment: Example of selecting multiple options and submitting a form: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#filling-in-forms.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this below code helps:

```
driver=new firefoxdriver();

//create select class object for selecting multiple select box field

Select s=new Select(driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("select[multiple='multiple']"));

/*you can use selectByVisibleText() predefined method of Select class for selecting multiple values*/

s.selectByVisibleText("Wheat - HRW");
s.selectByVisibleText("Wheat - White");
```