# After scrolling the page, xpath of a element is not present

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver

I have requirement that needs to check a  div on home page that contains sub images. I am trying like this

My Sample Code :

```
module.exports.openurl('www.google.com', "Online Shopping | Buy Phones, Computers,Fashion");
driver.sleep(5000);
module.exports.scrollto(0,400);          
driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.xpath(fexpath)).then(function(present){
    if (present){
        //goes logic here
    }else{
        //everytime its going here                
    }
```

Here I am getting false as return value. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide the full code and the HTML.

Comment: are you sure `fexpath` exists?  Are you really saying that if you comment out the `module.exports.scrollto(0,400);`, it works?  That sounds dubious to me . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions Guys

I have solved my problem by using the javascript executor. Below is the code:

```
var element = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(xpath));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Answer (score -1):

U should try scroll to element. it is in api. Element should be visible to interact with it.

also check:

1. Did it occurs when windows is maximized?
2. Did it work with css locator?
3. Is it browser dependent?(on all drivers or specific one).

Comment: -1 because: grammar, composition, sense. Please try and correct your answer and clarify what you mean by it.

Answer (score -1):

Best practices recommend to [use XPath as locator of last resort](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8470/how-can-i-structure-selenium-tests-in-a-way-that-minimises-the-maintenance-work/8491#8491). Did you tried locating element by ID or name? Or even CSS?

Comment: Citation of best practices describing XPath as 'last resort'?

Comment: see link added.